# Weak Convergence in a Normed Vector Space implies Convergence in Normed

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\textit{X}$ be a normed topologoical vector space. Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ such that $(x_n)$ converges to a $x \in X$ weakly. Then for every $\varepsilon >0 $ and for every $m > 0$ there exists a convex combination $y = \sum_n a_nx_n$ so that

\begin{align*}
||x - y|| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

for every $n \geq m$.

I have shown that $x$ is in the norm closure of the convex hull of the sequence, i.e., I have shown that $x \in (conv(x_n : n\in \mathbb{N}))^{=}$. So that means I have a sequence in the convex  hull converging to $\textit{x}.$ However, I am not sure how to control it with respect to $m$.

Comment: Maybe $\|x_n-y\|<\varepsilon$? I can't understand what role $m$ plays.

Comment: I am not sure either. I pulled this problem from Analysis Now by Pedersen. I have been messing with it for a few weeks and have gotten nowhere with it. It almost seems that we only care about the tails of each of these sums and not the whole sums.

Comment: If you wish to show the estimate holds for some $y\in{\rm conv} \{ x_i:i\ge m\}$, just apply your argument to $(x_n)_{n\ge m}$.

Comment: My edit was just for some typos.

Comment: Thank you Daniel.

Comment: @DavidMitra do you mind to clarify your hint? Do you mean like n this for $n >= m$, consider $conv(x_n : n >= m)$ and show that $x$ is in the norm closure of this (which is not hard to show), and use the fact that there is a sequence converging to x of the desired form.